# Recurrence relation for the number of ternary strings of length n that contain either two consecutive 0s or two consecutive 1s.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I'm having trouble with this one...I understand others have posted this it seems. However, I don't understand those answers/others some incorrect. I first tried thinking of the different ways this could happen, arranging each case i.e.

case 1: 2 followed by string of n-1 containing 00

case 2: 2 followed by string of n-1 containing 11

case 3: 10 followed by string of n-2 containing 11

case 4: 01 followed by string of n-2 containing 00

case 5: 011 followed by any string of n-3

case 6: 100 followed by any string of n-3

case 6: 00 followed by any string of length n-2

case 7: 11 followed by any string of length n-2

however, not convinced this is correct since im fairly certain there is some overlap/some possiblities im missing.

im assuming it would be a better idea to find ones that DO NOT contain "00" or "11" and subtract that from the total possible 3^n, but im not sure where to start...

Comment: The answer follows almost immediately from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739203/recurrence-relation-to-find-ternary-strings-of-length-n-that-do-not-contain-3 which gives a relation for strings containing neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: You’re right: it’s simpler to work with the complementary set. Let $a_n$ be the number of ternary strings of length $n$ that do not contain $00$ or $11$; I’ll call such strings *good* strings. Let $b_n$ be the number of these strings that end in $2$.

Suppose that $\sigma$ is a good string of length $n-1$. If $\sigma$ ends in $2$, we can append any of the three characters $0,1$, and $2$ to it to get a good string of length $n$; that accounts for $3b_{n-1}$ good strings of length $n$.

- If $\sigma$ does not end in $2$, how many different characters can be appended to $\sigma$ to make a good string of length $n$?
- How many good strings of length $n$ does that account for?

Putting the two pieces together will give you an expression for $a_n$ in terms of $a_{n-1}$ and $b_{n-1}$.

- Show that $b_n=a_{n-1}$ and use that to get rid of $b_{n-1}$ in the expression just mentioned. The result will be a recurrence for $a_n$.

To finish off, let $c_n=3^n-a_n$, so that $a_n=3^n-c_n$, and substitute into your recurrence to get a recurrence for $c_n$; that’s what you actually want.

**Added:** An alternative approach is to notice that each good string $\sigma$ of length $n-1$ can be extended in at least $2$ ways to a good string of length $n$. If $\sigma$ ends in $0$ or $1$, it can be extended in only $2$ ways, with $1$ or $2$ in the first case and with $0$ or $2$ in the second. If $\sigma$ ends in $2$, it can be extended in $3$ ways. Thus, every good string of length $n-1$ contributes $2$ good strings of length $n$, for a total of $2a_{n-1}$ strings, and those that end in $2$ contribute a third one as well. Thus, we need to know (in terms of the $a_k$’s) how many good strings of length $n-1$ end in $2$. Each of those strings is obtained by adding a $2$ to a good string of length $n-2$, so there are how many of them?

Comment: I'm pretty lost once you introduce sigma. Why are we concerned with strings that end with 2? And don't we usually concern ourselves with what the string starts with (as in the cases I wrote above) instead of how they end?

Comment: Ok, I understand your comment now...have to look at strings of length n-1 (otherwise we would be ignoring a possible occurence of 00 and 11 between the n-3 term and n-2 term). just wouldn't work...I finished the problem given your suggestions. I get $a_n = 2a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-1} + 3a_{n-1}$. That means the number of string that contain 00 or 11, or $c_n$, is $c_n=3^n-7a_{n-1}$. However, this isn't in terms of $c_n$. I don't get how you can get rid of the $a_{n-1}$

Comment: @ohbrobig: I’m going to add the alternative approach that you ended up using to my answer and then go through and delete all of my comments here; if you delete yours, we can clean this up a bit.

Comment: So are you saying that it should be $a_n = 2a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-1} + 3a_{n-2}$?

Comment: And aren't you supposed to end up with a recursive relation in terms of itself? I.E. $a_n$ in terms of $a_n$? How do we go from are relation which has a $a_n$ as well as $b_n$

Comment: @ohbrobig: No, not at all. There are $a_{n-2}$ good strings of length $n-2$. Each of them produces one good string of length $n-1$ ending in $2$: you just stick a $2$ on the end. Each of *those* produces $3$ good strings of length $n$. $2$ of those $3$ are already counted in the $2a_{n-1}$ term that we got from the fact that *every* good string of length $n-1$ produces (at least) $2$ good strings of length $n$. All that’s missing from that count is one extra good string from each of the $a_{n-2}$ good strings of length $n-1$ that end in $2$, so the grand total is $a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$.

Comment: @ohbrobig: The whole point of a recurrence relation is to express $a_n$ in terms of *earlier* terms of the sequence, terms $a_k$ with $k<n$. Expressing $a_n$ in terms of itself doesn’t help you to calculate it; expressing it in terms of earlier $a_k$’s means that you can calculate it by working up from the base cases.

Comment: **I understand that**.....but you have two recurrence relations (3 in fact). We need to end up with one. How are you ending up with one, that in your answer you have defined as $c_n$ in terms of earlier terms of the sequence?

Comment: @ohbrobig: I thought that you had abandoned my original approach in favor of the alternative one, in which case you have only $a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$. (This is also what the original approach gives you if you carry it out as suggested.) What you actually want is not $a_n$, but $3^n-a_n$, the number of strings of length $n$ that *do* contain $00$ or $11$. Call this $c_n$; now you want to express $c_n$ in terms of earlier $c_k$’s. Just do a substitution: if $c_n=3^n-a_n$, then $a_n=3^n-c_n$, and our recurrence is $$3^n-c_n=2\left(3^{n-1}-c_{n-1}\right)+\left(3^{n-2}-c_{n-2}\right)\;.$$

Comment: Now just solve for $c_n$ in terms of $c_{n-1}$, $c_{n-2}$, and some constant.

Comment: Its confusing because I find it more appropriate to call what we want $a_n$ and use $b_n$ for what we **don't want**, then simply subtract what we don't want from total possibilities. I'm not convinced its necessary to use a third variable $c_n$

Comment: @ohbrobig: In the alternative approach I *am* using just two sequences: $a_n$ for what we don’t want, and $c_n$ for what we do want. I used $a_n$ for what we don’t want simply because it’s what we actually work with directly, and I tend to use $a_n$ for that. In the alternative approach I could then have used $b_n$ for what we do want, but I didn’t want to use $b_n$ for two different things in the two approaches in my answer, so I used $c_n$ for what we do want, just as I did in the original approach. If you look at the alternative approach and my previous comment, which did almost all of ...

Comment: ... the remaining work, you’ll see that only $a_n$ and $c_n$ are involved: two sequences, not three.